# odoo13 error creating new product public category (eCommerce)

Tags: odoo-13

I have a problem after deleting a product parent public category. Now, to create a new public product category, I get the following error:

```
The post is missing or has been deleted.
(Entry: product.public.category (682,), User: 2)
```

Where 682 is the primary category database ID that was deleted.
I've deleted all public categories, but the error is repeated.
How to solve this?
I attach a screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l4kw.png)